# Understanding Stack Frames

Tags: c, stack

[image]

I have a few questions.

(1) `return address` means **where** the function is called?

(2) Why is there no stack frame for `h(int i)`?

Comment: The return address is where the function returns after the call ("the next line after the call," so to speak). When you are in `g()`, `h()` is not being called, thus no stack frame.

Comment: @DYZ, but it is called in f(int x) though?

Comment: Yes, but not at the same time with `g()`. A stack frame is created when the function is actually called, and destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: @DYZ, then why not write the stack frame of `h(b)` instead of `g(b + 3)`?

Comment: It depends on which of the two functions is executed first. In a single-threaded program, `g()` and `h()` have to be called one after another, and the order is chosen by the compiler.

Comment: @DYZ, I see, so if `h(b)` was before there would be stack frame for `g` instead only for `h(b)`? One more question, in the `main` stack frame, why is there `???` after `a`? Why isnt it the actual value of `f(2)`?

Comment: `a` does not have a value yet, because `f()` has not returned yet.

Comment: @DYZ, I think I am understanding this more. So everything is going synchronously? Like real time basically?

Comment: Correct, as long as there's only one CPU.

Comment: @DYZ, thanks! I am really getting it. Just one question, what does the return address to OS exactly mean from the main function?

Comment: That's the return to the operating system that called the main function in the first place. (Just like all other functions, `main` must be called by someone.)

Comment: @DYZ, I really appreciate all the help sir! Seriously appreciate it. I've understood much more because of you. Can't say thanks enough boss!